# How to determine the number of edges in this graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $Q_k$ be the graph whose vertex set corresponds to the set of all $01$-sequences of length $k$ with an edge between two vertices if the sequences differ in exactly one place.

Draw $Q_3$.(DONE)

Determine (with reasons) $e(Q_k)$ and show that $Q_k$ is bipartite.

My solution so far:

$d(G) = 2\cdot \frac{e(G)}{|G|}$ for a graph $G$.

So $e(Q_k)= \frac{1}{2} \cdot d(Q_k) \cdot |Q_k| $

Now  $|Q_k|  = 2^k$ since for a $01$ sequence of length $k$ we have two choices (0 or 1) for each position in the sequence, giving us

$|Q_k|  = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot ... \cdot2$ (k times) $=2^k$.

Now, I am not sure how to work out $d(Q_k)$, the average degree of $Q_k$. From drawing $Q_3$ which has $d(Q_3)=3$, I can guess $d(Q_k)=k$. But how would I go about proving this?

Also any hints on how to show  $Q_k$ is bipartite?

Note: If anything is unclear in the question or solution, please let me know and I will clarify it.

Comment: Hint: If you successfully split the set of vertices in two parts, you are done. Put the vertex $000\cdots 0$ in $V_1$ and all its neighbours in $V_2.$ They all have all zeros but one 1. Then prove that their neighbors (except $00\cdots0$) have exactly two $1s,$ and can be elements of $V_1,$ ...

Comment: When every vertex has the same degree, it shouldn't be hard to figure out the average degree.

Comment: @user376343 AH! Could you split it into one group with an odd number of zeros and another with an even number of zeros?

Comment: It is exactly what I mentioned!